# Why do I get an argument error?

Tags: ruby

This is copied from *Eloquent Ruby* book:

```
class Document

    def words 
        @content.split 
    end 
    def word_count 
        word.size

    end 
end 


doc = Document.new("Ethics", "Spionza", "By that which is...")

doc.word_count
```

I get this error:

```
`initialize': wrong number of arguments (3 for 0) (ArgumentError)
```

I do not understand why. What's wrong with this example?

Comment: This class has no defined initializer. What code, do you think, will handle those parameters and how?

Answer (score 2):

As has been mentioned, you need to define an initialize method.

In Ruby, the initialize method is an instance method called automatically when you use the `.new` class method, and the class method arguments are passed to the instance method.

You have three arguments: "Ethics", "Spionza" and ""By that which is..."

So because there's no `#initialize` method, the Ruby default is used, which expects no arguments but you're passing three.

(and you misspelled "Spinoza" :) )

In your use case it should probably look like this.

```
class Document

  def initialize(category, author, content)
    @category = category
    @author = author
    @content = content
  end

  def words 
    @content.split 
  end 

  def word_count 
    words.size
  end
end



doc = Document.new("Ethics", "Spionza", "By that which is...")

doc.word_count
```

Comment: Thank you guys for the help! I thought had to initialize the method, and I did, once but maybe I did it incorrectly. I appreciate the help.  I'm wondering why the book gave this example without putting in the initializing method. SMH!

Comment: Look at the chapter "Required Ceremony versus Programmer-Driven Clarity" -- I think that's where he discussed the `#initialize` method.

Comment: Most of his examples concentrate on the point he's trying to make, he doesn't usually include other code not directly related.

Comment: Ok, Thanks Mr. Turczyn, will do!

Comment: " I thought had to initialize the method, and I did, once but maybe I did it incorrectly." .... you know it has to be done every time you run the program? It has to be part of your source code. When you run a Ruby program everything starts from zero.  If you're running IRB it will remember previous class definitions, but when you exit and re-enter it will be back to a clean slate...

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified a constructor (`def initialize`) and the default constructor only takes zero arguments.

Add the `initialize` method to your class.

Answer (score 0):

As @fiskeben points out, you need to define an `initialize` method and specify the appropriate arguments.  The example below accepts 2 arguments, which are set as instance variables.

Note that the method body of the `word_count` method has been changed to access the `@content` instance variable (since it's not clear where the `word` variable in `word.size` is defined).

```
class Document

  def initialize(name, content)
    @name = name
    @content = content
  end

  def words 
    @content.split 
  end 

  def word_count 
    @content.size
  end 
end 


doc = Document.new("Book Name", "Book Content")

puts doc.word_count
```